# Error on importing 3rd party model into LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, model

I'm new to LTSpice but have the basics figured out (laying out a schematic, setting up simulation, running) and have done so with the basic but very well stocked library included. Of course my issue is I'm not using LT op amps.

I'm trying to import the [model for the LM4562](http://www.ti.com/product/LM4562/toolssoftware), but there are three options: PSPICE, and two TINA-TI which I'm not even sure what that is. The PSPICE package does not contain any .mod or .subckt files, rather it contains a .lib that has all the subcircuit information in it.

I have been trying for the last few hours to import the parameters and get it to work to no avail. All the tutorials are usually directed either at .mod files, or when I try to .INCLUDE the .LIB file, it throws errors that I don't fully understand.

I used the opamp2 symbol and modified it so that the pin names match up, or at least I believe I did (I could have done it incorrectly I suppose).

Below is a screenshot of the circuit I'm using to test it, and the error message I get:

[image]

Below is my Netlist:

D:\Projects\Electronics!TestCCt\opamp test.asc

V1 VCC 0 9

V2 0 VEE 9

V3 Vni 0 SINE(0 1 500)

R1 0 Vi 1K

R2 OP Vi 9.09K

XU1 Vi Vni VCC VEE OP LM4562

.INCLUDE D:\Library\Datasheets\Models\lm4562\LM4562.LIB

;op

.tran 0 25ms 0s 1ms

.backanno

.end

Errors are as follows. I'm not sure what nodes are floating:

**Circuit: * D:\Projects\Electronics!TestCCt\opamp test.asc

WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VP1 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:14 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VP2 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VP3 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VP4 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VZ1 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VZ2 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VZ3 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:U11:VZ4 is floating.
WARNING: Node U1:1:9 is floating.

Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
Starting Gmin stepping
Gmin = 10
Gmin = 1.07374
vernier = 0.5
vernier = 0.25
vernier = 0.125
Gmin = 1.02385
vernier = 0.0625
vernier = 0.03125
vernier = 0.015625
Gmin = 1.01955
vernier = 0.0078125
vernier = 0.00390625
Gmin = 1.0126
vernier = 0.00520833
vernier = 0.00260417
vernier = 0.00130208
Gmin = 1.00833
vernier = 0.000651042
vernier = 0.000868055
Gmin = 1.00696
vernier = 0.00115741
vernier = 0.000578703
Gmin = 1.00536
vernier = 0.000771604
vernier = 0.000578703
vernier = 0.000771604
vernier = 0.000578703
Gmin = 1.00449
vernier = 0.000434027
vernier = 0.000578703
Gmin = 1.00351
vernier = 0.000434027
Gmin = 0
Gmin stepping failed

Starting source stepping with srcstepmethod=0
Singular matrix:  Check node u1:1:u11:vz3
   Iteration No. 1
Singular matrix:  Check node u1:1:9
   Iteration No. 2
Could not converge to DC with sources off!
Starting source stepping with srcstepmethod=1
Singular matrix:  Check nodes u1:1:14 and u1:1:9
   Iteration No. 1
Could not converge to DC with sources off!
Singular matrix:  Check node u1:1:9
   Iteration No. 1
Fatal Error: Singular matrix:  check node u1:1:9
   Iteration No. 1

This circuit has floating nodes.**

What am I doing wrong, and more importantly, how do I import this model correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the op amp symbol you dropped in your schematic is not mapping to the correct pins on the device. What symbol did you use? You can make a new symbol and make sure the pin names match those in the .lib file...

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly that, as well, modifying "opamp2" and saving it as a customized symbol "TIopamp" - this is actually all taken from after I assured the pin names were the same. If I can take a screenshot or provide any other information please let me know.

I've also included this information in an edit in the above post for reference

Comment: Can you attach your netlist? (View->SPICE netlist)

Comment: I will try, one moment

There we are, see above

Comment: I see a few problems. If you look at the order of the pins in the netlist it does not match the order in the .lib file. Secondly, you have a negative voltage on your positive supply rail. Also, you have a positive voltage on your negative rail!

Comment: Could you explain the pin order in a bit more detail? I'm afraid I can't make that much sense of the netlist.

Also please note the polarities of the voltages are -9V to adjust for that. Not the prettiest fix but I was just doing it quick.

Comment: The line which defines your op-amp in the netlist is:
XU1 N002 N003 N004 N001 OP LM4562
The pin order in the subcircuit definition is:
.SUBCKT LM4562 Vinm Vinp VCC VEE Vout
These should match up, but if you track down the node names they don't. Do you see what I mean? It might make it easier if you explicitly label each node on the schematic.

Comment: Also, your supplies are the wrong polarity, even accounting for the negative sign. Notice that your symbol appears to have VCC on bottom and VEE on top...

Comment: Thank you for your patience and please see above. Here I gathered that "Vinm" was the non-inverting input... which I just realized is wrong. "m" = minus? I have since changed that but nothing is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15916/discussion-between-mjxs-and-user49628).

Comment: Notice that the signal inputs are still before the supply nets in the netlist. It believe it should be XU1 VCC VEE Vi Vni OP LM4562... It seems that LTSPICE is not mapping the pins correctly from your symbol. You can either fix this manually and run from the netlist or you can try to get to the bottom of it. It might work if you start a symbol from scratch instead of editing and old one? Just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
The first is:
Click on the ".OP" button, type .lib and insert it in Schematic, then with the right mouse button click on the created directive and go look for the LIB file (spicemodel) you want to implement, in the location where you saved it. Open Spice Model and look for the correct name of the document and insert a generic component, but of the same nature as yours, for example an NPN Transistor, then right-click on the generic component and change its name by the component name that is written in the Spice Model. Ready.
The second alternative is:
Open the Spice model with Ltspice, right-click on the Spice model's name, a list will appear, click on the "Creating Simbol" option, it will be in the Auto-Generated components folder in Ltspice, and there's still how to modify the created Symbol Layout if you want. Then just use it normally without having to use the ".inc" and ".lib" directives.